# "reveal" an image on iphone

Tags: iphone

i would like to reveal an image on an UIView:

1. showing an empty screen
2. slowly reveal the image from to to bottom

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]];

CGRect endFrame = img.frame;
CGRect startFrame = img.frame;

startFrame.size.height = 0;
img.frame = startFrame;

[view addSubview:img];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];

img.frame = endFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: This works fine, but I expect a different animation:
Your code is like a transformation, but I want to show the Image "row by row" ...

Comment: I'm confused then.  What do you mean by "row by row"?

Comment: I'll try to explain:
as you can remember, if you had a very, very slow connection (perhaps using a modem), downloaded images were displayed (slowly) from top to bottom. Thats what I want (like a scanner scans..)